# How to increment an integer by reference?

Tags: java, reference, integer

Is it possible to increment an `integer` value by reference?

```
int counterA = 0;
int counterB = 0;

int counter = (condition) ? counterA : counterB;
//use counter
counter++;
```

Result: both counterA + counterB will remain = 0, instead being incremented.

Comment: Nope, use a holder object, ex. `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: That's great, would you mind adding this as an answer. Probably what I was looking for.

Comment: @membersound No need. An answer with same idea posted :)

Comment: @Zéychin:  *Everything* is passed by value.

Comment: @Makoto You're correct. I'm going to drink more coffee now and cry over my having said that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a primitive type so there is no reference being assigned, only values. You can wrap it in a class:

```
public class IntegerHolder {
   private int value;

   public IntegerHolder(int value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   public void increment() {
       value++;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: OK I accept this as a valid answer, though one would probably perfer the use of `AtomicInteger` directly.

Comment: You could just use the Integer class.

Comment: @Zéychin no, it's immutable.

Comment: `Integer x = 0; x++;` is completely valid, as are the arithmetic operations.

Comment: It's still creating a new instance of an integer under the covers.  Don't let the syntactic sugar fool you.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to an int holder you can also use an array:

```
int[] counter = new int[1];

counter[0]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) :

```
AtomicInteger counterA = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger counterA = new AtomicInteger();

AtomicInteger counter = (condition) ? counterA : counterB;
counter.incrementAndGet();
```

In Java, all variables are pass-by-value, including primitive types like `integer` (and even objects but it may be confusing here, just check [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)).

You could be tempted to use `Integer` but wrapper classes are immutable. Instead you can use `AtomicInteger` which is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a wrapper object (the answer you've been provided by other users) you could just use an `if-else` statement and increment the values directly:

```
int counterA = 0;
int counterB = 0; 

if(condition)
{
    counterA++;
}
else
{
    counterB++;
}
```

This can become too wieldy if you have more than 2 counters though.